# Problem with parsing NSString to NSDate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, parsing, nsstring, nsdate

I have XML with this value:

```
<LastModifiedOnDate>2011-04-02T00:00:00</LastModifiedOnDate>
```

I am trying to parse this on iPhone from NSString to NSDate but have no luck.

```
NSDateFormatter *formate = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];  
        [formate setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss"];  
        //NSString *strConcat = @"2010-09-24 17:30:00";  
        NSDate *date = [formate dateFromString:string];
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need all those apostrophes in your format string. The only ones you need are around the T.

```
NSDateFormatter *formate = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];  
[formate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
// I recommend setting a timezone because it will use the system timezone and that
// can cause confusion with your data.  
// [formate setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
NSString *strConcat = @"2010-09-24T17:30:00";  
NSDate *date = [formate dateFromString:strConcat];
NSLog(@"Date: %@", date);  // remember NSDate default to current timezone when logging to console
```

If you string have fraction of seconds, then add SSS to your string format: `[formate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"];`

For additional information on date formatting check out [Unicode Technical Standard #35](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-10.html#Date_Format_Patterns).

Comment: It's work, but have one more problem. When HH:mm:ss is 00:00:00 conversion doesn't work, I got null?

Comment: you can do replacement on your string "00:00:00" with "00:00:00.000" so it will always have the fraction.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your's `SetDataFormat` function with below and let me know for the result ...

```
    [formate setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *string=@"2011-04-05T12:43:56.537";
NSDateFormatter *formate = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];  
[formate setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ss.SSS"];  
NSDate *date = [formate dateFromString:string];
```

its working..

Comment: Sorry I didn't paste whole data. This is value from XML it has '.537' for seconds and thats not work because of that extension. <LastModifiedOnDate>2011-04-05T12:43:56.537</LastModifiedOnDate>